# How to add char from a stream into a node?

Tags: c, linked-list, stream

Here is my code. I am stuck on add string of stream file into my linked list. For example, here I have a file called foo. In foo, it is formatted as following

12345678 12345678

1233 1389732

and so on. Which means I get each line of the file and only read the first string and add it into list. I checked add "a/b/c/d" on line 95.It works. So the insert function is working. The problem occurs on line 101. I don't know why the second line's value covered the first line's value.

Which means, when I print the list step by step, it prints out

a/b/c/d/12345678/

a/b/c/d/1233/1233/

I am stuck on why it did nit print a/b/c/d/12345678/1233 for second line?

Any suggestions about this?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h> 
#include <stdlib.h>


typedef struct n{
  char *value;
  struct n *next;
} Node;


void printList(Node *head){
  Node *cur = head;
  while(cur!=NULL){
    printf("%s/", cur->value);
    cur = cur->next;
  }
  printf("\n");
}

void insertIntoList(Node **head, char *data){
  Node *newNode = malloc(sizeof(Node));
  if (newNode == NULL){
    perror("Failed to allocate a new node for the linked list");
    exit(1);
  }
  newNode->value = data;
  newNode->next = NULL;

  Node *currentList = *head;
  if(*head == NULL){    //if the linked list head is null, then add the target into linked list
    *head = newNode;
  }
  else{
    while(currentList->next!=NULL){
      currentList = currentList->next;
    }
    currentList->next = newNode;
  }
}


int main(int argc, char**argv){
  FILE *fileStream;


  size_t len = 0;
  char *line = NULL;
  Node *head = NULL;


  int j;
  for(j=1; j<argc-2;j++){
    fileStream = fopen(argv[j], "r");
    if(fileStream == NULL){
      fprintf(stderr, "could not open");
      continue;
    }
    insertIntoList(&head,"a"); /////////////Line 95
    insertIntoList(&head,"b");
    insertIntoList(&head,"c"); 
    insertIntoList(&head,"d");
    printf("here is a try\n");
    printList(head);
    while(getline(&line, &len, fileStream)!=EOF){ /////////////Line 101
          char *targetNum = strtok(line, " ");
          if(strcmp(targetNum, "\n")!=0&&strcmp(targetNum,"\t")!=0&&strcmp(targetNum," ")!=0){
            printf("*****%s\n", targetNum);
            insertIntoList(&head, targetNum);
            printf("######print head here is##########\n");
          printList(head);
          printf("######print head here is##########->\n");
          }
      }
      //printList(head);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: For one thing, you only call `strtok` once for each line, so you fail to pick up the second substring in each line. Secondly, I don't understand why you are checking `strcmp(targetNum," ")`, and check for `\n` and `\t` when they could be part of the delimiter string too. You have already removed any possibility of finding a `space` with `strtok`. Time for a read of the `strtok` man page? Can't yet spot the worse problem though.

Comment: @WeatherVane I only want to pick up the first substring of each line so I call strtok() once. The strcmp(targetNum, " ") check if the line contains any whitespace.

Comment: Then all you need to do is `strtok(line, " \t\r\n");` and remove the faffing around. The token pointed to will not contain any of the delimiter character set.

Comment: @WeatherVane Thanks for the suggestions. And I still don't know why I can't add the first substring of the second line into list successfully. When the program call the first line and the first substring can be added. But when the program call the second line of the file, the targetNum removed the previous one also...

Comment: please see my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is, that you are only storing the *pointer* in your list, not the actual data.

The first 4 items all have different memory locations, so they remain distinct.

But the next two have the same memory location, so the data is the same for both, which is the most recent data placed at that location.